# Is there are a way to filter by _score in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

Is there a way to do following `post_filter` query valid?

I've tried different ones: `_score`, `score`, `doc.score`, `doc._score`, `_source.score` etc. nothing is working.

I believe there should be some solution that allows you to filter in the `post_filter` by the score.

```json
{
  "body": {
    "post_filter": {
      "script": {
        "script": "_score > 100 && _score < 200"
      }
    },
    "query": {
      "function_score": {
        "functions": [{
          "script_score": {
            "script": "doc['price'].value * 100"
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  },
  "index": ["items"],
  "type": []
}
```

Similar question on the ES group: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Filter-on-score-td4044742.html

Comment: Have you tried min_score? I think it will help you with part of your question. [link]https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-min-score.html

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I found this solution, but it solves problem only partly.